# Unix shell script to reformat the tabbing/indenting in code files based on curly braces

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, formatting, indentation

Unix shell script to reformat the tabbing/indenting in code files based on curly braces.

Looked around and found a way to do this in vim, using visual mode and the equals sign, but I can't seem to find a way to do it using an external unix shell script. The idea is to be able to run:

```
./scriptName filename(s)
```

And all files would be indented according to depth of curly braces. It doesn't have to add in extra newlines/return carriages, just indent based on depth.

```
namespace Mine {
    Class Yours
    {
        Yours() { something something; }
        ~Yours() { something
            something more }
        Yours(too)
        {
            etc.
        } }    // Programmer put two braces on the same line, don't do anything
}
```

I can sort of imagine using an environment variable to keep track of the depth of braces, and then trimming the spaces on each line and adding spaces as needed, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/).

Comment: The options to `indent` are quite comprehensive. If I remember correctly, you can save a cfg file for indent. Figure out the option settings you like, save them to a cfg file, and then it will just work the way you want each time. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, `indent` does not understand `//` comments, which is strange for GNU indent, given the C extensions in gcc. See http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html#SEC15